# cuModuleGetFunction don't accepts simple kernel names, only ".entry"-tags from .ptx-file

Tags: cuda, cmake

I convert my .cu-files using CUDA_COMPILE_PTX from findPackageCUDA.cmake. When I try to get the function-pointers to my kernels I am facing the following problem:

My kernel named Kernel1 only can be loaded correctly via cuModuleGetFunction if I use its .entry-label from the resulting .ptx-file, e.g. _Z7Kernel1Pj

The problem is that this label may change each time I have to recompile my .cu-files. This can't be a solution if I reference them by name in a constant char*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

_Z7Kernel1Pj is a C++ mangled name. If you want to have a simple symbol you can use extern "C"

```
extern "C" void Kernel1(...)
```

For example if you use the default CUDA visual studio project contains the kernel

```
__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
```

If you run cuobjdump -symbols on this you will see the mangled symbol name

```
STT_FUNC         STB_GLOBAL   _Z9addKernelPiPKiS1_
```

If you use extern "C"

```
extern "C" __global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
```

the symbol name will now be

```
STT_FUNC         STB_GLOBAL   addKernel
```

Using extern "C" will result in loss of function overloading and namespaces

Comment: OK, thank you! But is there a possibility to predict the C++ mangled version of my kernel-names, so that I can hardcode them as strings in my code?

Comment: By the way, how do you load your kernel functions with the driver-API? I couldn't be the first one facing this problem, am I?

Comment: CUDA uses a GNU3 demangler so you can learn the format but this is just error prone. The best approach is the compile your program and run cuobjdump -symbols on your executable to get a list of the symbol names. If you can't pick out the correct one you can run a demangler utility on the symbol names.

Comment: OK that appears to become a huge overload and I can't even do it from inside my code, but only with external command-line tools as I understand. So I prefer the "extern C"-solution, but thank you as well!

Comment: Your options are (1) add a build step that uses cudaobjdump or parses .ptx files for the names, (2) use extern "C", or (3) write a mangler and pass the full C++ name to the function. I would recommend (1) and (2). I use the driver API often and I use option 2 and option 1.

Comment: Thank you Greg! I have find my solution in (2) by the way. I get around the lack of function overloading by including my vector-type-operation-header outside the extern "C" scope.